# logout button doesn't work MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a logoutbutton looks like

```
<article class="PanelTextRight">
    Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
    <article class="LogBtn">
        <input type="submit"   id="btnLogOut"  value="Log Off">
    </article>
</article>
```

then I add this script

```
<script>
        $(document).delegate('#btnLogOut', 'click', function () { location.href = 'AccountController/LogOff'; });
    </script>
```

all work except the button of logout , any idea how to fix it I have a logout Action looks like

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    WebSecurity.Logout();
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username", false);
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

how to fix this button , it give error

```
The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

 Requested URL: /AccountController/LogOff
```

Comment: Can you post the html from the logout form?  Have you set a breakpoint on the Action to see if it is being hit?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Any error? Is your controller action getting hit when you hit the logoff button?

Comment: @ramiramilu I updated my question please check

Comment: @AMH Did you end up finding a solution to this? was it a typo issue?

Answer (score 0):

Set button id and catch it with javascript. You can use delegate $(document).delegate('#btnid', 'click',function(){ location.href = 'controller/methodname'; });  try something like this. And make sure that tis kind of script is added right in script that loads on page load.

Comment: it give error 
The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

 Requested URL: /AccountController/LogOff

Comment: remove the word Controller. The path you are looking for is URL: /Account/LogOff

Answer (score 0):

Your action has a `[HttpPost]` attribute, your JS code is making a `GET` request. Try removing the attribute, or even better have your js do a POST.

Comment: how to make js do post please

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

You should not include the word 'Controller' as part of your path:

```
$(document).delegate('#btnLogOut', 'click', function () { location.href = 'Account/LogOff'; });
```

Also remove the `HttpPost` attribute from your Action, as you want to allow logging off from `GET` requests

Comment: same error Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

 Requested URL: /Account/LogOff

Answer (score 0):

Your action is HttpPOST method, change it to HttpGET and also remove ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute.